# trigger 2 functions on an onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am calling 2 functions on an onclick event of a button , first function to check the form validations and the next one for hiding the form if and only if the validation is true. But the problem here is when i click the Button both the functions are been simultaneously called and eventhough validation is false form gets hided quickly. Any solution to this would be helpful . THANKS

```
       <p><input type="button" name="send" value="Hide Entries" onclick="validate(),hide();"></p>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:php], but is, instead, [tag:javascript]-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call the `hide` function with in the `validate` function

```
function validate()
{
   //other validation code
   hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> both the functions are been simultaneously called

No, they're not, JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (barring the use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)). They're being called one after another, because you haven't done anything to tell the interpreter not to run the `hide` function if `validate` returns false.

The minimal change would be:

```
<p><input type="button" name="send" value="Hide Entries" onclick="if (validate()){hide();}"></p>
```

...if you want `hide` to only be called if `validate` returns a truthy value.

---

**Off-topic** (slightly): The larger change would be to move the JavaScript logic out of the HTML markup and into a proper script. Recommend reading up on [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_Javascript). But the above should work with your current structure.